# Hoisted method in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, methods, hoisting

I would like to learn the proper way to hoisted method in object.
My goal is the put the object definition at the end of the code, and the object usage at the beginning. Let's say:

```
doing stuff with o

let o = {
    bar: 1,
    foo: function() {
        console.log(this.bar);
    },
}
```

Of course, if I'm writing :

```
o.foo();

let o = {
    bar: 1,
    foo: function() {
        console.log(this.bar);
    },
}
```

`o` is undefined because the object is declared after the usage.

I thought about this trick :

```
o = returnO();
o.foo();

function returnO() {
    return o = {
        bar: 1,
        foo: function() {
            console.log(this.bar);
        },
    }
}
```

which works but I would like to know if there's not a better way to avoid the statement

```
o = returnO();
```

Thanks.

Comment: why do you want to achieve this?

also you are talking about hoisting functions but `o` is actually not a function

Comment: Why do you want to use it before defining it? What's led you to think that's a good idea?

Comment: @ Ashish singh : the purpose is not the o object, but the usage of the foo method inside o. When you declare method inside object, as far as I know, you can't declare it with a function declaration, it must be a function expression.

@ Utkanos : it seems more easier for me to get the usage of your objects at the beginning of your code (for instance, if you have an object managing ajax request and some statements to assign it to some element of your page). But it's only a question of point of vue, my first purpose was to find any way to use a function declaration for defining an object method

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's the purpose of what you want to accomplish, maybe you're practicing.

The problem is the post declaration of the variable, the engine at this point of the interpretation of your code `o.foo();`, the variable `o` was declared but not yet initialized.

You can use a function declaration (Hoisted function) as follow, and use it as a constructor which is similar to what you want to accomplish:

```js
new A().foo();

function A() {
  this.bar = 1;
  this.foo = function() {
    console.log(this.bar);
  };
}
```

Comment: To be precise, `o` was declared, but not assigned with the object.